# liquibase command line: Cannot find the declaration of element 'changeSet'

Tags: xml, liquibase

I'm trying to organize my changesets such that there is one changeset element per file, as implied by the [Liquibase Best Practices](http://www.liquibase.org/bestpractices.html), but I get the following error when i try to use the validate command on my liquidbase xml files.

> liquibase: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element
>   'changeSet'. liquibase: Error thrown as a SAXException: Error parsing
>   line 3 column 38 of ./1.xml: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of
>   element 'changeSet'.

What am I doing wrong?

master.xml:

```
<databaseChangeLog
    xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:ext="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.1.xsd
    http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-ext.xsd">

    <include file="./1.xml"/>
    <include file="./2.xml"/>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

1.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<changeSet  id="1" author="me">
    <createTable
        tableName="CLIENTS"
        ...
    </createTable>
</changeSet >
```

Comment: Set Liquibase plugin version in pom.xml to latest => https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.liquibase/liquibase-maven-plugin

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Each included file needs to have the same XML root node as a standard changelog - so your 1.xml should look like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<databaseChangeLog
    xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:ext="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.1.xsd
    http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-ext.xsd">
  <changeSet  id="1" author="me">
      <createTable
          tableName="CLIENTS"
          ...
      </createTable>
  </changeSet >
```

You may also need to specify in the master changelog that the included files are relative to the master changelog.

```xml
...
  <include file="1.xml" relativeToChangelogFile="true"/>
...
```

Whether you need to do that is dependent on how you run liquibase.

Comment: I have not included any files, still getting same error.

Comment: Vikash, you commented on a very old question/answer. If you are having a similar problem, and this answer did not help you, then you should probably open a new question with your own particular details.

Answer (score 3):

Refer to the post here - http://forum.liquibase.org/topic/declaration-not-found-databasechangelog . 
Changing the xsd version from 3.0 to 2.0  in xml file worked for me.