# Maven build failing with Liquibase: cvc-elt.1 declaration of element cannot be found

Tags: xml, maven, xsd, liquibase

I'm completely new to Liquibase and I setup a rather simple project to become familiar with Liquibase. Unfortenately, I seem to fail at the very first steps which is very frustrating.

First my changelog.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<databaseChangeLog
        xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:ext="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
        http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.1.xsd http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext
        http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-ext.xsd">

    <preConditions>
        <dbms type="mysql"/>
    </preConditions>

    <changeSet id="1" author="maik">
        <sql dbms="mysql" endDelimiter=";">
            CREATE SCHEMA ods
        </sql>
        <createTable tableName="department">
            <column name="id" type="int">
                <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false"/>
            </column>
            <column name="name" type="varchar(50)">
                <constraints nullable="false"/>
            </column>
            <column name="active" type="boolean" defaultValueBoolean="true"/>
        </createTable>
    </changeSet>

</databaseChangeLog>
```

Besides that, I have a liquibase.properties:

```
driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
classpath=lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.41-bin.jar
url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/prime
username=bla
password=bla
```

My pom.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>himstedt</groupId>
    <artifactId>liquibase</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.41</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
                <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <propertyFile>src/main/resources/org/liquibase/liquibase.properties</propertyFile>
                    <changeLogFile>src/main/resources/org/liquibase/changelog.xml</changeLogFile>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>update</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

When I run mvn package I get the following error:

```
user@desktop:~/IdeaProjects/liquibase$ mvn package
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building liquibase 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ liquibase ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- liquibase-maven-plugin:3.0.5:update (default) @ liquibase ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Parsing Liquibase Properties File
[INFO]   File: src/main/resources/org/liquibase/liquibase.properties
[INFO]   'classpath' in properties file is not being used by this task.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Mon Mar 20 13:28:20 CET 2017 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
[INFO] Executing on Database: jdbc:mysql://localhost/prime
INFO 20.03.17 13:28:liquibase: null: null: Successfully acquired change log lock
SEVERE 20.03.17 13:28:liquibase: null: null: cvc-elt.1: Deklaration des Elements 'databaseChangeLog' kann nicht gefunden werden.
INFO 20.03.17 13:28:liquibase: null: null: Successfully released change log lock
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.909 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-03-20T13:28:20+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 19M/472M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:3.0.5:update (default) on project liquibase: Error setting up or running Liquibase: Error parsing line 9 column 75 of src/main/resources/org/liquibase/changelog.xml: cvc-elt.1: Deklaration des Elements 'databaseChangeLog' kann nicht gefunden werden. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Project structure is:
[Project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aAZTd.jpg)

For me this seems like a problem with the schema, but I double-checked and cannot make out a problem. Most probably I am missing something very obvious here.

Comment: Your posted changelog.xml XML file is valid as it is against the `http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.1.xsd` XSD.  Try checking (1) network connectivity to the XSD from the machine where validation is failing, (2) that the changelog.xml file you posted is the same as is yielding the validation error, (3) that the changelog.xml file you posted is not part of a broader tree of [included XML files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23540464/liquibase-command-line-cannot-find-the-declaration-of-element-changeset).

Comment: 1) I can open that link the the schema successfully in the browser.
2) I checked the chamgelog.xml again, the file given above is the file in the project.
3) I have one changelog/changeset file only, that is the one given above.

Comment: Edited first post for more information.

Comment: A guess in the wild: use the same version of liquibase-core and liquibase-maven plugin. E.g. set version of liquibase-maven-plugin to `<version>3.5.3</version>`

Comment: @Jens That did the trick. Thx.

Comment: @Brausepaul: You can accept it as an answer and with it mark your question as solved...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure to use the same version of liquibase-core and liquibase-maven plugin. 
E.g. set version of liquibase-maven-plugin to `<version>3.5.3</version>`