# How can implement seperate xmls for Liquibase in Spring Boot (Cannot find the declaration of element 'changeSet')

Tags: java, spring-boot, liquibase

I have a problem in defining seperate xmls Liquibase in Spring Boot.

1.xml, 2.xml and 3.xml are located under changes folder

Here is **db.changelog-master.yaml** shown

```
databaseChangeLog:
  - includeAll:
      path: "/db/changelog/changes/"
```

Here is **1.xml** shown below

```
<changeSet id="1" author="author">
    <createTable tableName="phone_numbers">
        <column name="id" type="bigint" autoIncrement="true" nullable="false">
            <constraints primaryKey="true" />
        </column>
        <column name="create_date" type="timestamp" defaultValueDate="CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" />
        <column name="update_date" type="timestamp" defaultValueDate="CURRENT_TIMESTAMP}" />
        <column name="country_code" type="int" nullable="false" />
    </createTable>
</changeSet>
```

Here is **2.xml** shown below

```
<changeSet id="2" author="noyan">
    <createTable tableName="roles">
        <column name="id" type="bigint" autoIncrement="true" nullable="false">
            <constraints primaryKey="true" />
        </column>
        <column name="create_date" type="timestamp" defaultValueDate="${now}" />
        <column name="update_date" type="timestamp" defaultValueDate="${now}" />
        <column name="name" type="varchar(30)" nullable="false" />
        <constraints uniqueConstraintName="UK_ofx66keruapi6vyqpv6f2or37" unique="true">
            <uniqueConstraint columnNames="name" />
        </constraints>
    </createTable>
</changeSet>
```

Here is **3.xml** shown below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<changeSet id="3" author="author">
    <createTable tableName="users">
        <column name="id" type="bigint" autoIncrement="true" />
        <column name="create_date" type="TIMESTAMP" defaultValueDate="CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" />
        <column name="update_date" type="TIMESTAMP" defaultValueDate="CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" />
        <column name="username" type="varchar(255)" nullable="false" />
        <column name="phone_number_id" type="bigint" defaultValueNumeric="NULL" />
        <constraints primaryKey="id" />
        <constraints uniqueConstraintName="UK_ain6rnqaxwdkd2y7039apay37" uniqueColumns="status" />
        <constraints uniqueConstraintName="UK_r43af9ap4edm43mmtq01oddj6" uniqueColumns="username" />
        <constraints foreignKeyName="FKsm22r0ln4w8wg55nd1iyddkpv" referencedTableName="phone_numbers" referencedColumnNames="id" baseColumnNames="phone_id" />
    </createTable>
</changeSet>
```

I got the error when I run the application.

Here is the error shown below.

```
Error parsing line 1 column 34 of db/changelog/changes/1.xml: cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration of element 'changeSet'.
cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration of element 'changeSet'.
```

How can I fix the issue?

Comment: Duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23540464/liquibase-command-line-cannot-find-the-declaration-of-element-changeset

Comment: @Katy I already looked through this link before but it didn't help me fix the issue.